# gatsbyjs, reactjs - why components are rendering twice and images do not appear?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am new to `gatsbyjs` and using v2.
I've 3 components - loader, header and layout.

`layout.js`

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Header from "./header"
import Loader from "./loader"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "./layout.module.css"

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query SiteTitleQuery {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              title
              menuLinks {
                name
                link
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Helmet
            title={'tite'}
            meta={[
              { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
              { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
            ]}
          >
          </Helmet>
          <Loader />
          <Header menuLinks={data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks} siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
            <div>{children}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    />
  )

  export default Layout
```

In `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default () => (
  <Layout> 
  </Layout>
)
```

Every component is being rendered twice as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Another issue I am facing with images. All the images are in `src/images/` and when I use it as below in `header` component:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import styles from "./layout.module.css"

const logo = 'src/images/logo.png';

const Header = ({ siteTitle, menuLinks }) => (
  <header className={styles.header_area}>
    <nav className={`${styles.navbar} navbar-expand-lg ${styles.menu_one} ${styles.menu_four}`}>
        <div className="container">
            <a className="navbar-brand sticky_logo" href="#">
                <img src={logo}  alt="logo" />
```

The image doesn't show up on a page. I checked Source in chrome developer tools and found that images are not being served via `webpack`.

So, **why components render twice and why image doesn't show up ? what am I missing or doing worng here ?**

Comment: I think you should be importing the image as if it was a module

Comment: @andresmechali tried but didn't work. something's wrong with gatsby-config. it's not serving images.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when using the `gatsby-plugin-layout` plugin. The doc is not really clear, but when using the gatsby-plugin-layout plugin, you don't need to wrap your page between the `Layout` component. That plugin takes care of this automatically. If you explicitly wrap your JSX between the `Layout` component, the `Layout` is rendered twice.

Comment: Life saver. Made the same mistake. Now working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your page is loading double components, are you coming to the site directly, or from another path?

---

For your image not showing up, this is why:
Everything in your `src` folder is meant to be dynamic, meaning it won't be served directly. If you want to include image statically, you can create a `public` folder in your root directory (at the same level with `src` folder), and put images in there. Anything in this `public` folder will be served directly. So for example, you can have this structure:

```
 |-- src
 `-- public
       `-- images
            `-- logo.png
```

Then in your code, you can include the path like

```
<img src="/images/logo.png"  alt="logo" />
```

---

I think for a logo like your use case, this method is sufficient. However, if you always link images like this, you'll be missing out a lot of gatsby's cool feature. For example, gatsby can load your image lazily, or optimize the file size! You can learn more [here (gatsby official blog)](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/).